# Can we run different versions of VFP for different users for A/B testing in Salesforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am planning to enhance a VFP.

Wants to expose different GUI for different set of users using Permission set. However, do we need to create different set of VFP or Do Salesforce provides any options to run different versions of VFP for different set of users.

For example out 100 users, 90 will be accessing the existing VFP page and New enhance version of the page will be given to 10 users. We can manage the user access using permission set to different VFPs; However, curious to see any other suggestions from the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new Visualforce Page. There is no native A/B testing feature on the platform.

One approach to this problem is to test the changes in a sandbox with a handful of users before implementing in production. You can collect feedback without modifying production data this way, and you'll probably get the same feedback as if it were live.

Also, you could deploy your own A/B testing tools if you want to use the platform's tools. For a Visualforce you could have a main page that displays the actual page with an iframe. Like this:

```html
<!-- vf main page -->
<apex:iframe src="{!pageNameVariable}" />
```

```
// apex code
pageNameVariable = '/apex/EmbeddedFile';
```

To do this A/B testing you would have to figure out a way to fill in the variable with the appropriate page name (e.g: `PageA` and `PageB`) using, say, custom settings or a field on the user record.